# How to use multiple consumers to consume messages from multiple SQS queues?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-sqs

I am currently working on a Java application which will be able to consume messages from SQS and pass on the list of messages to client that is using this application.
Now I want to ask if the client of my application wants to poll messages from multiple queues then how can I implement that ?

Q.) Why client will be polling from multiple queues at same time?
->  Suppose the client is dependent on multiple upstream services for its data so TYPE1 data will be pushed to queue1 by Service 1, TYPE2 data will be pushed to queue2 by Service 2 and my client will need both TYPE1 and TYPE2 data to process the feature that they want to implement.

Example: Giving a hypothetical example(because it will totally depend on the client's upstream services), Suppose the client of the application will allocate the total car price that a customer has to pay for that car.

Now, the Upstreams teams can be Interior design team, Engineering team etc

```
 TYPE1 data pushed to queue 1 by Interior design team = X$ (Cost for interior design of car)
 TYPE2 data pushed to queue 2 by engineering team = Y$(Cost to build the core features of car)
```

Now these two services are independent so the client shall be using 2 different queues to get their outputs but to allocate overall price of car these both outputs are important.
So these two queues won't have same data that's why I want to know is there any way in which **multiple consumers can be built to consume messages from "n" number of queues** (depending on the client that will be using my application)?

Comment: I think you are looking for this:  https://theburningmonk.com/2018/04/how-to-do-fan-out-and-fan-in-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: For 10k users: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66917515/2442804

Comment: For OP: you should not use SQS for this. You should have consumers for the different messages and each consumer updates a record in a database and then maybe checks if all messages are there - and if all messages have arrived / the record is complete then do something with the data. But the way you want to consume messages from multiple queues simultaneously is not useful / feasible. E.g. how do you recover from the server crashing between deleting the first and the second message, then you have broken data in the queues. How do you deal with a message not coming in at the right time? Etc....

Comment: Note that the fact that the two services belong to two different teams is NO argument against them sending to the same queue. If you decide your API is not a Web API but simply a single SQS queue then that is completely fine, you can give both teams permission to write to the same queue.